# How to uninstall pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin, python

I successfully installed pgAdmin4 with

```
pip install pgadmin4-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But afterward, `pip list` doesn't show anything related to pgAdmin, so I don't know what argument to pass to `pip uninstall <package_name>`.

If i do `pip uninstall pgadmin4`, i get:

> Cannot uninstall requirement pgadmin4, not installed

Should I just delete the virtual environment directory where I installed pgAdmin?

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo apt autoremove pgadmin4
```

works for ubuntu version 18.04

Comment: sudo apt purge  pgadmin4;
sudo apt purge  pgadmin4-desktop;
sudo apt purge  pgadmin4-web;

Answer (score 1):

It didn't install or you're using the wrong `pip`. On Ubuntu, you probably want the package [`pyton3-pip`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/python3-pip), which runs as `pip3` (the `python3` version of pip)

```
pip3 uninstall pgadmin4
Uninstalling pgadmin4-2.0:
... a bunch of files
Proceed (y/n)? 
  Successfully uninstalled pgadmin4-2.0
```

By any means pgadmin4 runs under 2.7 and 3.x, so make sure you're using the same pip you used to install pgadmin4.

As a side note, you can `pip uninstall ./pgadmin*.whl` if you still have the wheel.

Comment: pip -V returns `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
`.  So I installed under version 2.7.  Besides, pgAdmin4.py is located on `lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4` (from the virtual env root).  That same pip is the one which doesn't list or uninstall pgAdmin4.  I already tried `pip uninstall ./pgadmin*.whl`, but I get the same result: `Cannot uninstall requirement pgadmin4, not installed`.  If nothing else works, would there be any problem If I just delete the virtual environment directory?

Comment: Forgot to mention: The installation suceeded because I can access pgAdmin from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for any future people: it appears you need to go back into your virtual environment before running your `pip uninstall` command. For me that meant doing the following:

```
cd ~/.pgadmin4
source bin/activate
pip uninstall pgadmin4
deactivate
```

I actually still had the wheel, so I used that after `pip uninstall`but I think it's the same because `pip list` showed it there but it didn't before going into the virtual env.